# embedding my linkedin post feed on my website

Tags: linkedin-api

I wish to embedding my linkedin post feed on my personnal website.
I find some stuff for doing that with wordpress... but, without using wordpress... I do not find anything...

I find it strange to have plugin to do this on wordpress and nothing exists outside...

i found this link : https://www.linkedin.com/biz/000000/feed?start=0&v2=true
it would be just to replace the 000000 with the numbers in the url of the linkedin profile you wanted to access.
but it does not work all the time ... I think it does not work for "normal users" who do not have a company account preceded by "biz"

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

There is alternate way to accomplish this process. LinkedIn has an option called developer plugin here is the link below,
 https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile.
 Step to get the code
1. sign in with your LinkedIn account 
2. go click on your button get code and paste it anywhere in your html page.

Comment: This is no longer supported among others:
Member Profile (disabled)
Company Profile (disabled)
Company Insider (disabled)
Jobs You Might Be Interested In (disabled)
Alumni Tool (disabled)

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/myusername" style="text-decoration: none;color: #92ca55;"><img src="mydirectory/linkedin-icon.jpg" style="display: block;margin: 0;padding-right: 5px;float: left;"></a>
```

This will include the small linkedin icon on your page. Clicking it will send people to your linkedIn profile.

Comment: I'm sure you want to keep your page secure and stuff, but here is a hint to putting in the correct linkedin.com data: http://linkedin.com/company/ibm links to IBMs page: https://www.linkedin.com/company/1009/. You will have a similar shortcut.

Comment: "view profile" will send you to your personal profile. This is what you must use for the href section.